# System-wide app availability in Linux - Local user vs. VNC session

Tags: root, users, vnc

I have installed nvm (as root user) in my linux system (Ubuntu 22). On that time, I was connected by using a VNC session. The app is available every time I'm connecting with VNC.

The problem I'm facing is that my system is reporting nvm as not being available when I'm connecting locally, from the terminal, when I'm using the same user (root), unless I'm executing 'source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh', and after that I will be able to access nvm; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found

What is the difference between the two ways to connect to the system by using the same user, root?

Thank you.

Comment: Installing something in an arbitrary directory doesn't make it available for any user. Executable are expected to be found in certain dirs - `echo $PATH`.